# Sessions breaking

Tags: php

A client of mine has installed a simple server configuration onto his office PC. It all works (PHP & MySQL) but something is going on with sessions.

If I have login window as a separate popup (on any browser), the session keys generated in the window don't go to the opener - even if I send session id to it on the address bar.

The same login system works on every other server (including my default WAMP installation) but the client's one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set

```
session.use_cookies
```

To the value 1 in the php.ini configuration file on the server, usually located in the PHP install directory. Then restart Apache.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need to check the client web browser, did he use IE7/8 with Vista?

PHP Session normally  needs cookie enable, if it's not enable then, you will not be able to login no matter how you pass the session id.

Comment: Well, as I said it's not browsers fault. The same system works on other servers (using the same browser).